# Redirecting primary domain

Tags: drupal, web, drupal-7, hosting

This is a generic webhosting question,

I am trying to redirect, my primary domain to a subfolder in the 'www' folder, which consists of 3 folders
here is a better view

```
www ->
      Folder1
      Folder2 
      Folder3
```

Folder2 is where my drupal installation is , and this is where I want my domain to go directly

Right now what is happening is I type my domain name in the browser, abc.com, then I am presented with the above mentioned 3 folders and when I click the subfolder2, I can use drupal as per normal.

I am not sure what is needed to be changed, I am sure this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of web server have you got? Is it one you are self hosting?

If it's apache you can change the home page to point to the new folder. HOWEVER if you are remotely hosting it this may be more difficult and you may have to physically move the whole installation to the root.

Another solution (not a nice one) is to do an HTTP redirect by creating an index.html in the home folder with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;Folder2"></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?Primarydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ Folder2 [L]
```

Comment: this .htacess is where inside the main host rootfolder or the drupal folder?

Comment: Inside main Root. @noobprogrammer